# Max length of password that can be encrypted

Tags: encryption, cryptography, password-encryption

I am using PBEWithMD5AndDES algorithm to encrypt a password. I need to store encrypted password in a db column. Based on password length, i have to decide the length of db column. I want to know what can be the max length of a password that can be encrypted using the mentioned algorithm.

Comment: Do you really need to store passwords in the reversible form? If the passwords are intended for client user authentication, you may want to read following guide https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/

Answer (score 2):

1. If this is a password for access to something(s) on your system, you shouldn't store it encrypted at all, you should instead store an irreversible *and slow* hash, sometimes disguised as a PBKDF (password-based key derivation function). This provides much better security, which is offtopic for SO but has been discussed thousands of times at great length on security.SX and to a somewhat lesser extent on crypto.SX. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords for the canonical, and many links.
2. If you actually do need to store encrypted, PBEwithMD5andDES is not secure. Any value you store encrypted with this algorithm can be easily decrypted in hours at most and probably seconds by a competent attacker, so it's hardly worth the effort of encrypting.
3. Those said, to answer the only Q you asked: there is no inherent limit on the size of data that can be encrypted insecurely with this algorithm. Like all Java `Cipher` instances it uses an `init, update, doFinal` structure, and although the Java language limits the size of the `byte[]` arguments passed or returned on one call to slightly less than 2^31 (about 2,100,000,000) bytes, you can make any number of calls. (For *secure* ciphers there are some limits on data size, depending on algorithm and mode, to remain secure, but since this one is not secure to start with it doesn't lose anything by exceeding the data sizes that could reduce security.)

   It will take increasing amounts of *time* to process more data, because this cipher uses CBC mode which cannot be parallelized or pipelined on encrypt. I haven't measured and anyway it will vary depending on your hardware and to some extent your Java version, but if for example you want to encrypt 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 bytes it will probably take somewhere in the range of 300,000 years. Your computer may not last that long.

   OTOH since you want to store the result in a database, there will almost certainly be some limit there. Even if there is no architectural limit, or no effective one, every database is ultimately limited by the size of the disk or equivaent storage it can use, and the total of all storage in data centers (admittedly not all) is [estimated as approaching 2,000,000,000,000,000,000 bytes](https://www.statista.com/statistics/638593/worldwide-data-center-storage-capacity-cloud-vs-traditional/).

Comment: `PBEwithMD5andDES .. value can be easily decrypted in hours at most and probably seconds` - Along the MD5 being broker itself and DES being very short, at the end the attacker would need to find a 64-bit unknown key. It takes a little bit more than a few days. (I agree that whatever has MD5 or DES in name should be skipped today).  If I missed something or are do you have any resource, how the PBE (combination of MD5/DES) could be broken quicker, could you pass a reference? (I'm trying to find out if I misunderstood anything)

Comment: @gusto2: DES keys are 56-bits, not 64-bits.